# How to avoid the code lose while upgrade the plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been using wordpress plugins and I have  customized one of my plugin but I don't want to lose the code what I have created while we upgrade the plugin,is there any way to customize the plugin out side of that plugin folder so we can control it from the theme of the wordpress or some where else.Do any one have solution for this if so please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nice question !! But I think the only way is strictly not to upgrade your wp once all completed on your site & have a backup if by mistake someone upgrade it you have your backup.

Comment: Also I think you can get it done by using filters & hooks in your theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to use `hooks` & `filters` in your wp-theme.

Have a look at:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

http://themeshaper.com/2009/05/03/filters-wordpress-child-themes/

Comment: I got it worked,I did not add the apply_filters in the plugin function that was the reason. But when we upgrade the plugin it won't be available in that function so we need to add it manually after plugin upgrade?

Comment: Try to create your function & apply filter in your function.php file of the theme and not in that plugin

Comment: But I need some values which is only available in that plugin function only so how to get those values in function.php